# Any tools for Understanding  Existing Foxpro Database Model?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foxpro, database-migration

I have some dbf files of foxpro database. However, I have no idea about what are relationship between tables regarding foreign key, what tables are inter related and so on. Is there any tool which can help me to learn relationships easily. I mean which can draw relationship instead of me figuring out by hit and try.?
I want to export this database to Microsoft SQL Server. So I want to learn whole database schema to learn tables logic.
Thanks

Comment: See this question regarding fox pro migration tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415061/migrating-from-visual-foxpro  After the tables have been moved to SQL, you can use the database diagram tools in SSMS to set up foreign keys if the migration tool didn't already import them.  To find foreign keys look for columns in table B that have the same name as the primary key in table A. Those are foreign key candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this just a set of VFP free tables or is there a VFP database, as well? If there's a database, you'll have files with DBC, DCT and DCX extensions. If you have those, open the database and take a look:

```
OPEN DATABASE whatever
MODIFY DATABASE
```

If there are relationships defined between the tables, you'll see them there.

VFP ships with a program called GENDBC that will generate code to recreate a database. Since it's all SQL code, that might help you to see what's in there, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Stonefield Database Toolkit](http://www.stonefield.com/sdt.aspx) is designed to work with Visual FoxPro and has a lot of documenting ability. Not free though.