# Is there any way to retrieve a schema from a directory of fox pro 9 free tables?

Tags: database, database-schema, foxpro, visual-foxpro

While looking for a way to discover the relationships between fields in Sage ABRA Suite I came an answer that sounded like if you have a free table directory with Visual Fox Pro, you're going to be stuck guessing at what the schema really is:

> "Is this just a set of VFP free tables or is there a VFP database, as
>   well? If there's a database, you'll have files with DBC, DCT and DCX
>   extensions."

- from [Any tools for Understanding  Existing Foxpro Database Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154533/any-tools-for-understanding-existing-foxpro-database-model)

Is this really the case?  I checked my ABRA installation's Data directory (a free table directory according it's ODBC connection) for files with *.DBC, *.DCT and *.DCX extensions and I didn't find any of them.

Comment: Can you clarify further what you need to accomplish? When you say schema, what pieces of information do you need, other than table and field names, types etc...?

Comment: I mean primary and foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a situation where it is just free tables you will only establish the schema in terms of inter-table relationships and the general structure of how the data hangs together if this has been published by Sage, because there is no metadata anywhere defining this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a license to MSDN Professional (or higher) you have a license to Visual FoxPro. Looking a the structures is as simple as:

```
USE {table name} NOUPDATE
MODIFY STRUCTURE
```

If you don't have Visual FoxPro via MSDN, and all you need is the structures for the tables, you might find something like this useful tool: DBF Viewer 2000

http://www.dbf2002.com/

It looks like you can modify the structures so you should be able to peek into the structures as well. Not a bad solution for $50. Free trial so you can see if it works.

Comment: @leeand00, Careful on the DBF Viewer... I worked with one (not positive of version) and if the table had an auto-increment column, the DBF viewer broke the link if any attempt to edit any data occurred. -- again, just a cautionary note.